# Помогите понять асинхронность

Tags: c#

В моем большом приложении наступил момент, что нужно сделать долгие операции такими, чтобы они в отложенном режиме выполнялись  и не мешали основному потоку. Простые примеры я смотрел все вроде понятно, если метод сложнее, то получается каша. ВОт код для постановки задачи. В нем комментированы строки, где я пытался разными путями запустить задачу, вот мой алгоритм понимания, подскажите где я не прав.

1. Создаем создаем метод в виде асинхронной задачи Getpage.
2. Создаю главный асинхронный метод,в котором также присутствует моя асинхронная задача из п.1. Оператор await я ставлю перед асинхронной задачей( метод), тем самым я даю понять компилятору, что эта задача внутри моего метода будет выполнятся асинхронно.
3. Пытаюсь в методе Main запустить задачу асинхронно  несколькими способами.

По логике я понимаю правильно? Что нужно для асинхронной задачи создавать внешнюю Таску? Как правильно это все организуется.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Web;

namespace probaparser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Info i = new Info();
            string urrrla = "https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1?page=0";
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", GetResumme(urrrla)));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Создаю метод ввиде задачи, которая будет выполняться асинхролнно.
        public static Task<string> Getpage(string url)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://google.com"; // Реферер. Тут можно указать любой URL

            using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(httpWebResponse.CharacterSet)))
                    {
                        // читаем ассинхронно построчно
                        return reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // метод который выполнятся должен асинхронно.
        // await поставил перд методом, тип которого задача,которая возвращает
        public static async Task<List<Info>> GetResumme(string ReadyString)
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(await Getpage(ReadyString));
            var list = new List<Info>();

            // получаем резюме
            var items = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='visitor-resume-list']/li");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h2[@data-ga='resumeListItem']").InnerText;
                var data = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='title-']/following-sibling::div")
                    .SelectNodes(".//p");
                var salary = item.SelectSingleNode(".//b[@class='salary-']").InnerText;
                var Prof_info = item.SelectNodes(".//dl[@class='prof-path-']/p");

                string kartinka;

                try
                {
                    kartinka = item.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='vrloa-img img_zoom']").Attributes["href"].Value;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    kartinka = "Нет изображения";
                }

                string Data = string.Join("\n", data.Select(x => string.Format("  {0}", x.InnerText.Trim())));

                if (Prof_info != null)
                {
                    string prooof = string.Join("\n",
                        Prof_info.Select(x => string.Format("   >{0}", x.InnerText.Trim())));

                    list.Add(new Info()
                    {
                        VacansName = name,
                        Name = Data,
                        Salary = salary,
                        Expiriens = prooof,
                        Foto = kartinka
                    });
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс для организации коллекции, он вспомогательный.

```
public class Info
{
    public string VacansName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // public string PojelaniyKRabote { get; set; }
    public string Expiriens { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public static string VakansyRubrick { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Приведите МСВП для вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Anamnian Что есть МСВП?

Comment: [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Anamnian Дак я и привел минимальный пример ввиду двух методов, и пытаюсь понять где я сделал не правильно.

Comment: Вот ответьте на один вопрос... Вы уважаете себя? Да и как относитесь к нам? **Все** ваши вопросы были отредактированы из за ужасно отформатированного кода. Вам хоть самому нравиться то, что вы видите? Мне - нет... Зачем нам знать о вашем namespace, о всех using, зачем нам пустые методы, конструкторы (по типу Info()), зачем нам все ваши комментарии, зачем нам уйму пустого пространства, ну и почему все так "танцует" (ведь сама студия выставляет вам все отступы так, как положено). В общем, в будущем буду минусовать за такое...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Принял учту.

Comment: Логично разделить задачу на параллельные нити (thread), в них, согласно логике приложения внедрять Task с await внутри методов.

Comment: `static Task Main(string[] args)` и `string.Join(" ", await GetResumme(urrrla))`